# Highchart 3D Pie Chart Label color?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to use a dark background for my HighChart 3D Pie Chart. By default, the text is black with white glow.

My goal is to have something similar to:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-gradient/dark-unica

I'm using the WordPress plugin `wpdatatables` to create the actual pie and was given the following support:

> "You can check in our documentation about `wpDataCharts` callbacks. Every chart exposes a number of options that customize its look and feel. Charts usually support custom options appropriate to that visualization. This callbacks  allows adding options that are available in Google Charts API, Highcharts API and Chart.js API"

https://wpdatatables.com/documentation/information-for-developers/wpdatacharts-callbacks/

I tried the following code based on support and HighChart website

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  if (typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined') {
    wpDataChartsCallbacks = {};
  }
  wpDataChartsCallbacks[14] = function(obj) {
    obj.options.plotOptions.series.dataLabels.color = '#FF0000';
    obj.options.chart.backgroundColor = '#GG0000';
    obj.options.chart.zoomType = 'x';
    obj.options.chart.panning = true;
    obj.options.chart.panKey = 'shift';
    obj.options.tooltip = {
      formatter: function() {
        var s = '<b>$' + this.y + '</b>';
        return s;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I added that line:

```
obj.options.plotOptions.series.dataLabels.color = '#FF0000';
```

but doesn't seems to be working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm, what code did you use for your background color? In your code sample, you have `'#GG0000'`, which is not a valid HTML color.

Comment: Sorry i just used a random color... it was #FF0000.  ..

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Wordpress callbacks as you are doing, but whenever I need to update a chart's options, I've found that you need to refer to the series as an array, even if you have only one in your chart.

Try this and see whether it works:

```
obj.options.plotOptions.series[0].dataLabels.color = '#FF0000';
```

**Update:** Please see the comment from @ppotaczek below for the correct syntax.

Comment: Hi Mike Zavarello, this is not correct code. Plot options allow you to set some options to all series. 
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series
More likely solution would be to use: obj.options.series[0].dataLabels.color = '#FF0000';